# How to save doccano database to Google Cloud Storage after deploying to Cloud Run?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, doccano

I deployed a doccano docker container to Cloud Run and I am successfully able to reach the WebApp.
Everything works fine, such as log in, data import and annotation.

Now I would like to connect the container to Google Cloud Storage in order to save all annotations in a bucket. Currently, all data is lost after the container restarts.

Any hints on how to accomplish that are highly appreciated!

What I (kind of) tried:
Container is up and running, some environment variables are set. But I don't know how I can set a bucket uri within the doccano docker container (doccanos documentation is a bit sparse in that regard).

Comment: Can you use a simple linux path to save your annotations?

Comment: It's not only about saving the annotations. It would rather like to set a path to a storage bucket, so doccanos database is being imported from that place and every time the container exits, the annotations are stored safely there.

Comment: I don't know doccanos in detail, but you can't have database on Cloud Run. You have to use external database. If you can't configure external/3rd party database, Cloud Run is not the right service for you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be helpful for anyone with a similar use case:

My solution/workaround for deploying doccano on GCP was deploying a docker container to the Compute Engine (and opening a port to the app) instead of Cloud Run. Cloud Run seems indeed to be the wrong service for that use case. Compute Engine has a persistent storage which keeps all of the data even if the container has to restart.